# Find a script that uses MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am editing a system which was built by another programmer at my company.

System is made using PHP and uses Send Grid for mail delivery. I just add email addresess for sending mails and all works well, but I can't find the script that writes incoming mails to database, so I can't retrieve new incoming e-mails.

Is there a way to determine which script writes to the database?

Comment: If u have a seperated file that makes connection to database (for example connection.php) just check in which files this file is included

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know which database engine is used, for a MySQL database search your code, for example with netbeans "Find in project", with the keywords: `mysql_` or `mysqli`.

Other classes used for database access are PDO and ODBC, for that you should search after `PDO` or `odbc_`.

[PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
[ODBC Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-autocommit.php)

Answer (score 0):

There's possibly no "standard" way to do this. I would suggest the following: Open the whole thing in an IDE (like Netbeans for PHP) if you haven't already and then do a file search for e. g. the name of the table that is concerned. Or for commands starting with `mysql` / `mysqli`, if you don't know.

If the project is running in Linux, you could also try

```
cd /path/to/project/sources
find | xargs grep mysql
```

(Replace `mysql` with `mysqli` or the table name.)

Another approch would be to force an error: Cut the database connection or rename the table(s) or something like this. PHP will throw an error that would hopefully occur in your logfiles, stating where it occured (PHP script and line).

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the mysql general log and figure out which queries are coming from the input script, then you can determine the incoming IP for those queries. Watch the processlist for the incoming queries and then do a netstat -anp on the remote IP to track down which process is generating those queries.